# How do you change the hash algorithm in mysql?

Tags: mysql, security

I just noticed something about MySql which I haven't noticed before.

If you use any of the MySql hashing functions MD5, SHAx, Password, etc they all seem to return the same hash. This happens across all schemas and databases regardless of their installed instance

I have a local MySql server database, and two others hosted with different internet providers

If I do the following

```
  select MD5('Password');
  select Sha1('Password');
  select Sha2('Password', 224);
  select Password('Password');
```

each function will yield the same result across all for that function across all instances of MySql

For example if I do `select MD5('Password')` it gives this same `dc647eb............12b3964`  hash for MD5 regardless of on all of my servers. This looks a little bit suspect to me and sounds like a security hole.

Has anyone noticed this and is there anything that can be done about it?

Comment: [`SET PASSWORD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) is used to set passwords now, so `PASSWORD()` is not relevant. Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I get different results for each of them.

Comment: I also get different results for these: `dc647eb65e6711e155375218212b3964`, `8be3c943b1609fffbfc51aad666d0a04adf83c9d`, `a1308b7983fef7def9ffd06bed7ff767fa4216baf9d9d911af1e7e2e`, and `*FBA7C2D27C9D05F3FD4C469A1BBAF557114E5594` respectively.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qnZxTzXy7iy1MViC5PH3jv/0

Comment: By "instance" do you mean that it always produces the same output, unlike Bcrypt which does not? If so, that's just how MD5 works, and why MD5 is a huge problem from a security perspective. SHA1 and SHA2 likewise have similar limitations and cannot be trusted for hashing passwords. Password-specific hashes like Bcrypt have a random salt component built-in as part of them that makes the output random and a lot harder to brute-force guess.

Comment: Yes I mean I can log on to that server (phpmyadmin) run the command and I get the exact same result @tadman accepted re `Password()` I meant the same function across different servers

Comment: Why is that unexpected? If they didn't produce the same result consistently, how would you use them?

Comment: This is the expected behavior by design. These hashing functions should always produce the same results given the same inputs, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use it to check data integrity. If you want different values per instance you need to use a technique called [salt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))

Comment: I would have thought each instance (server) would have given a different result for the same function. so `md5()` on one server would give a different hash on a different server

Comment: These are cryptographic *signatures*, not unique password hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5, SHA1 and SHA2 are simple cryptographic hashes that for any given input *will*, by design, produce *exactly* the same output. This is how they are intended to be used. You don't want the SHA2 file signature of something to come out differently each time you run the hash. They're also designed to be fast to compute.

You want things like `SHA2(x)` to always produce the same output for any given `x` so that if you have a file and a signature you can see if the file has been in any way tampered with by computing the hash and comparing it.

Password-specific hashes like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), which you might be thinking of, work differently and produce random output. This makes them way more resistant to brute-force password guessing attacks. They're also designed to be slow, often tens if not millions of times slower than their MD5 or SHA counterpart.

You want, effectively `BCRYPT(x)` to be *random* and unpredictable for any given `x` so that you cannot infer `x` from the output.

Yes, using MD5 or SHA for passwords is a huge security problem *especially* if the input is unsalted. Just search for `dc647eb65e6711e155375218212b3964` in your favorite search engine and see what comes up: it's instantly "dehashed". You can use a search engine as what used to be termed a [Rainbow Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

SHA and MD5 were used, extensively, for hashing passwords mostly because it was the best option at the time. Computers were also far, far slower, and GPU options didn't exist, so the risk of compromise was vastly reduced. Now tools like [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) exist that can crack even "difficult" passwords if someone's careless enough to use a weak hash.

Comment: There's books on the subject worth reading, like [Applied Cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied-cryptography/) if you want to know more.

Comment: No offense, but if you don't understand cryptographic hashes you need to learn more. There's no shame in admitting you don't know everything, or in learning. Hubris is how we get in trouble. MD5 is pretty foundational, it's one of the earliest popular hashing methods, so not knowing how it works is a sign you need to learn more.

Comment: No offence taken and I do understand crypto hashes. I just had a different expectation that's all. I want just expecting MySql to do something clever and save me some work. Like I say I in C# I usually write/reuse my own encryption classes. I don't do MySql/Php that often so I've never worried about before now it or even looked into it. I (wrongly) assumed Oracle and their cohorts know way more about this kind of stuff that me so I thought they might help me out a bit.

Comment: "A different expectation" is another way of saying "I guess I didn't understand". This is fine if you're just learning, but it's a huge problem if you roll your own crypto. **Do not do this**. Even security professionals know better than to do that.

Comment: I didn't understand from the MySQL perspective as I don't do much with that and was honestly hoping it would be taken care of by MySql doing something clever like seeding with some random value that it gets from the server or something. And when I say roll my own I mean on top of the exiting Crypto functions, I didn't mean my own from scratch, that's just too much work and I agree not a good idea.

Comment: Whew, well, that's a good thing. Far too many problems in the security world are caused by people who, having all the right intentions, go and do the absolutely worst thing possible. MySQL's crypto functions are pretty weak, they're not useful for much of anything in my opinion, so it's usually better to lean on more robust implementations offered by your application layer where you can use more modern hashes and encryption algorithms.

Comment: I agree. If I need anything heavy-duty I'll do it in the asp.net core. PHP I just use for lightweight stuff, even then, now armed with this new info I'll add extras on top of their crypto function so my hashing will be app-specific and that little bit more robust.

Comment: Both PHP and C# are fine here, they're equally capable when it comes to this sort of stuff if only because [libsodium](https://doc.libsodium.org) has been ported to pretty much everything by now.